# How to make invisible button on widget with background image?

Tags: c++, qt5, qwidget, qpushbutton

I want to make a simple application with invisible button.

I set background image for my widget by UI property styleSheet and Resources -
 *border-image:url(:/image.jpg)*.
I always get something like this

[image: this]

and then I try to add button on it

I was trying with

```
ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{background: transparent;}");
ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);");
```

and it works with buttons on default background, but not in my case.

Every button that I add takes default parent background image. I dont want to see any hints of a button, but when I click on an area to be able to perform some functionality.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->centralWidget->setStyleSheet("background-image:url(:image.jpg)");
    ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{border:none;}");
}
```

Code an above makes button flat, but it duplicate background image from parent widget anyway.

Have you any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Why do you use `border-image` ? If you want to set the background image, use `background-image` instead. Moreover, in the code you provided, the second `setStyleSheet()` overwrites the first one (that become useless). Then, the second stylesheet is incorrect.

Comment: @Fareanor, I use it because I need to fit background image into the widget. Sample code Is not that I actually use - just for example.

Comment: This is not the meaning of `border-image`.

Comment: @Fareanor, but there's a trick with

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do. But if you want to make the button invisible, just remove the borders (`"QPushButton {border: none;}"`) and call `pushButton->setIcon(QIcon());` to clear the displayed image. It should work.

Comment: @Fareanor, It doen't work

Comment: Try to not set the image with stylesheets but with `setIcon()` too. This way it will work (I did it and it worked well).

Comment: @Fareanor, I dont get it. What did u exactly do?

Comment: First of all, tell me what you exactly want to do. Because setting an image to remove it afterward is a nonsense, you better have to not set the image at all. Your question is not clear, explain what you want to do and I will be able to give you the real solution.

Comment: @Fareanor, I want to have invisible button on an image, that of course must not be the button entirely.

Comment: Ok so the image is not the button's background. If I understand. Try to only set `"QPushButton {border: none;}"` for the button. In my case, it disappears.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example. But the stylesheet you used to set an image is invalid because you did not specify the related widget it refers to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Cause

A common misconception is that when a stylesheet without a [selector](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) is applied to an element, then it is used only for that element. In fact all element's children are styled as well. Thus a selector should be used to achieve the expected result.

## Solution

I would suggest you to change this line in your code

```
ui->centralWidget->setStyleSheet("background-image:url(:image.jpg)");
```

to

```
ui->centralWidget->setStyleSheet(".QWidget { background-image:url(:image.jpg) }");
```

**Important:** Note the dot before `QWidget`. It means *style the QWidget, but exclude the subclasses*. This is necessary because `QPushButton` is a subclass of `QWidget` and otherwise would be affected as well.

Then you can set the `pushButton`'s backgroung color to transparent as you do with

```
ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{background: transparent;}");
```

## Example

Here is a simple example I have prepared for you in order to demonstrate the proposed solution (requires `cat.png` in the resource file under `pix/images`):

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) :
        QMainWindow(parent) {
        auto *widget = new QWidget(this);
        auto *button = new QPushButton(widget);

        widget->setStyleSheet(".QWidget {"
                              " background-image:url(':/pix/images/cat.png');"
                              " background-repeat: no-repeat;"
                              "}");

        button->setStyleSheet(".QPushButton {"
                              " background-color: transparent"
                              "}");
        button->move(100, 100);
        button->resize(100, 100);

        connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, [](){
            qDebug("clicked");
        });

        setCentralWidget(widget);
        resize(600, 480);
    }
};
```

## Result

The given example produces a window with a background and a 100x100px invisible clickable area positioned at (100, 100):

[image: Window with a background and an invisible button]

Comment: I didn't think of the inheritance between `QPushButton` and `QWidget`. Your solution is better than mine so I upvoted you. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Fareanor, you are welcome! Actually, I don't find it very intuitive either, but it is what it is. :(

Comment: In fact I'm really surprised. What you explain makes sense but... I never encountered this error even though I often have set a QWidget stylesheet over custom widgets. But in this case, the error occurs (that's why I had to add _"background: transparent;"_).

Comment: @Fareanor, I assume that you haven't noticed it because you apply the stylesheet correctly by putting a dot in front of the class name in the selector, so the sub-classes are not affected.

Comment: No I hadn't. You just learned me that we can do this with a dot. I think I just got lucky. From now on, I'll add this dot on my future applications that will request it. Thanks for the tip anyway :)

Comment: @Fareanor, :) To be honest, I don't like stylesheets, because they are limited and behave strangely. Normally I prefer to paint the widget myself, as you do in your answer. For example, check out [my repository of custom widgets](https://github.com/scopchanov/flat-gui).

Comment: Yes I understand. I just made a test and writing the dot before QWidget for a custom widget (that inherits `QWidget`) does not work. Even worse, the stylesheet is not applied at all. Very strange indeed.

Comment: @Fareanor, for a custom widget you have to put the name of the custom class instead of QWidget and to enable the stylesheets with `setAttribute(Qt::WA_StyledBackground);`.

Comment: It worked. You learned me two things today ahah :). I will correct my answer then. It seems to work even without setting this attribute though.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to answer here than in comments.

You just have to set the following stylesheet for your `QPushButton` to make it invisible:

```
QPushButton
{
    border: none;
}
```

I've made the test and it worked well.

For the tests, I have set the wrapping widget's `background-image` property. I also did another test with the `background-color` property instead. It worked in both cases (whether the background is a plain color or a picture/photo).

I hope it helps.

---

**EDIT:**

I have written a widget that performs what you want. And I also provided a windows in order to make the below example minimal and complete so that you can reproduce it.

I have tested it and it worked well.

*test.h*:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>

class WidgetWithHiddenButton : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    protected:
        QPushButton * invisible_button;

    public:
        WidgetWithHiddenButton(QWidget * parent = nullptr);
        QPushButton * getButton();

    protected:
        void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) override;
};

class TestWindow final : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    private:
        WidgetWithHiddenButton * widget;

    public:
        TestWindow();
};

#endif // TEST_H
```

*test.cpp*:

```
#include "test.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QStyleOption>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

WidgetWithHiddenButton::WidgetWithHiddenButton(QWidget * parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    // build your widget as you want.

    invisible_button = new QPushButton("Here is a button", this);
    QVBoxLayout * lay = new QVBoxLayout;
    QHBoxLayout * inner_lay = new QHBoxLayout;
    inner_lay->addStretch();
    inner_lay->addWidget(invisible_button);
    inner_lay->addStretch();
    lay->addLayout(inner_lay);
    this->setLayout(lay);

    this->setStyleSheet("WidgetWithHiddenButton {background-image: url(path_to_image/image.jpg);}");
    invisible_button->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border: none;}");
}
QPushButton * WidgetWithHiddenButton::getButton()
{
    return invisible_button;
}
void WidgetWithHiddenButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QStyleOption opt;
    opt.init(this);
    QPainter p(this);
    style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
}

TestWindow::TestWindow()
{
    resize(500, 300);

    widget = new WidgetWithHiddenButton;
    this->setCentralWidget(widget);

    connect(widget->getButton(), &QPushButton::clicked, qApp, &QApplication::quit);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    TestWindow tw;
    tw.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Feel free to adapt it (especially by changing the class name because `WidgetWithHiddenButton` is very ugly :) ).

**Notes:**

- I have written a text in the button in order to make it visible (for tests purposes) but you can remove it if you want the button completely invisible.
- I connected the `QPushButton::clicked()` signal to the `QApplication::quit()` slot in order to perform an action when we click on the area of the button.
- I redefined the `paintEvent()` method because it is needed when using `Q_OBJECT` macro alongside stylesheets over a custom `QWidget` as the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) mentioned.
- Feel free to modify the way I build the widget in the constructor (layouts, sizes, ...) to make it fit your requirements.

Comment: I dont know, that am i doing wrong or I poorly explained my problem. I dont get your point. This is the [result](https://pasteboard.co/Is3tR5B.jpg) of your answer. I have the visible button yet. Every button that I add takes default parent background image. I dont want to see any hints of a button, but when I click on an area to be able to perform some functionality.

Comment: @KkVova If you use QtDesigner as it seems, don't set the stylesheet from here but from the C++ code. I have never used any designer, that's why I can't know its behaviour. I have written everything in C++ in my example.

Comment: I delete all styleSheet mentions from Qt designer and take [the same result](https://ibb.co/C5Wqzm3) from the code.

Comment: Ok, I don't understand then, it worked for me. I tried with `QPushButton` as well as `QToolButton` and it worked the same. Perhaps if we can see your code...

Comment: @KkVova I can't see it because my network access is restricted. I would suggest you to edit your question and put your code here.

Comment: @KkVova Your code seems fine. I don't understand why your `QPushButton` copies the background of another widget. I never had this behaviour. The error shall come from somewhere else in your code but I can't guess where.

Comment: It appears with this simpliest code on 3 machines, including 2 win10 and one VM MacOS. Could you, please, share some working example to me?

Comment: I'll do better, I'll create a `QWidget`'s subclass that does what you want.

Comment: _I don't understand why your QPushButton copies the background of another widget_ - see my answer for an explanation and a very simple solution.

Comment: @KkVova My solution works but I think the one provided by **scopchanov** is way simpler.